# What difference between Self and the struct name produces this error?

Tags: rust

This code works fine:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    data: Vec<&'a str>,
}

impl Foo<'_> {

    fn bar_func(arg1: &str) {
        let f = Foo { data : arg1.split_whitespace().collect() };
        println!("{:?}", f.data);
    }    
}

fn main() {
    Foo::bar_func(&"hey split me!");
}
```

But if I change Foo for Self when creating the struct:

```
fn bar_func(arg1: &str) {
    let f = Self { data : arg1.split_whitespace().collect() };
    println!("{:?}", f.data);
}
```

I get a lifetime error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:9:31
  |
6 | impl Foo<'_> {
  |          -- lifetime `'2` appears in the `impl`'s self type
7 |
8 |     fn bar_func(arg1: &str) {
  |                       - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
9 |         let f = Self { data : arg1.split_whitespace().collect() };
  |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  |
  = note: requirement occurs because of the type `SplitWhitespace<'_>`, which makes the generic argument `'_` invariant
  = note: the struct `SplitWhitespace<'a>` is invariant over the parameter `'a`
  = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance
```

Until now I assumed that these would be interchangeable, and I tend to use Self most of the time, so you can imagine, this got me stuck for a very long time, and it was just luck how I found that it worked fine with the struct name when trying to isolate the problem in a minimal example.

Are they not equivalent, and if so, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

They're not the same.

`Foo` is `Foo<'_>`, with inferred (or elided) lifetime, and that means we can use the lifetime of `arg1`.

`Self`, however, keeps generic parameters of the current type, and that includes lifetimes. Thus, the lifetime of `Foo` with `Self` refer to the elided `'_` in `impl Foo<'_>`, which is a distinct generic lifetime that is incompatible with `arg1`'s lifetime.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chayim. Would you be able to link me to where I can read more about this? Your answer goes a bit over my head I'm afraid. I understand now that they are different but would like to dig more to understand fully. Ta!